# iOS app constrained to dimensions of 4S screen

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app and for some reason it started only rendering in iPhone 4S dimensions. The issue started happening when I upgraded a bunch of packages and messed with the Info.plist, project.pbxproj, and *.xcscheme a bit (too much it seems).

Here's a screenshot on an iPhone 6:

[image]

When I run it on a 4S it looks normal.

Any ideas?

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing this and it was related to the launch screen in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned this happens when `Launch Screen File` is empty. Verify in XCode under the 'General' section that `Launch Screen File` is not empty:

[image]